# Screen not load after start up on 18.04 with multiple monitors

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have clean installed ubuntu 18.0 and I my desktop screen is not loaded when I boot system and log-in.

Login screen looks fine, but after log-in I can see only my wallpaper with no icons and other GUI elements. I tried clicked with mouse on screen but nothing happened.

Temporary solution is plug out second monitor before I boot system until I log-in into system, and next plug-in back. After this everything working fine.
I I plug-out monitor after booting with 2 monitors I got black screen on plugged monitor and I need restart PC as well.

Can you tell me how can I fix this issue? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Open the gnome tweak tool and activate show icons

Comment: I cannot see any GUI elements, terminal, gnome menu ... nothing but wallpaper